# Proving the chain rule by first principles

Tags: analysis, functions, derivatives, proof-writing

I'm currently trying to prove:

$(f(g))'(a)=f'(g(a))*g'(a)$

I have been given a proof which manipulates:

$f(a+h)=f(a)+f'(a)h+O(h)$ where $O(h)$ is the error function. However, I would like to have a proof in terms of the standard limit definition of $(1/h)*(f(a+h)-f(a) \to f'(a)$ as $h \to 0$

Thanks!

Comment: I would love to answer but the way the OP, on [this other page](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/763491/6179), apparently silently downvoted the two answers posted and never answered the queries for clarifications, is making me shy.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since $g$ is differentialiable at the point $a$ then it'z continuous and then 
$$\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=g(a)$$ 
hence

$$(f\circ g)'(a)=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(g(x))-f(g(a))}{x-a}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(g(x))-f(g(a))}{g(x)-g(a)}\frac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-a}\\=\lim_{y\to g(a)}\frac{f(y)-f(g(a))}{y-g(a)}\lim_{x\to a}\frac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-a}=f'(g(a))g'(a)$$

Comment: One has to be a little bit careful to treat the case where $g$ is constant separately but it's trivial to see so it's not really a problem.

Comment: ...or the case where $g(x) = g(a)$ infinitely often in a neighborhood of $a$, but $g$ is not constant. ;)

Comment: Well written, Sami!