# Using first principles find derivative of ln(sec(x))

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

The question is to use first principles only.

Thus I started with the same and got

$$
y = \ln(\sec(x))
$$
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\ln(\sec(x+h)) - \ln(\sec(x))}{h}
$$

after this I do not understand how do I eliminate the $h$ in the denominator. I tried to implement $\ln(A) - \ln(B) = \ln\bigl(\frac{A}{B}\bigr)$ which ultimately led to

$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\ln\bigl(\frac{\sec(x+h)}{\sec(x)}\bigr)}{h}
$$

here I converted $\sec()$ to $\cos()$

$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\ln\bigl(\frac{\cos(x)}{\cos(x+h)}\bigr)}{h}
$$

Still I cannot proceed further.

Comment: You could try using Taylor series expansion of cos(x) and see what happens.

Comment: Try using the trigonometric identities : $\cos(x+h) = \cos x \cos h - \sin x \sin h$.

Comment: https://socratic.org/questions/find-the-derivative-of-sec-x-using-first-principle

Well here's a link that will solve your problems

Comment: well that link is for solving derivative of sec(x) but here it is ln(sec(x)) @nishant singh

and using taylor series i can expand it but then how will i eliminate h in the denominator

Comment: Make life easier :  $\log(A)-\log(B)=\log \left(\frac{A}{B}\right)=-\log \left(\frac{B}{A}\right)$ Now expand the cosine ...

Comment: Using trinometric identity : $cos(x+h) = cos(x)cos(h) - sin(x)sin(h)$ I have reached to this position 
$$
lim_{h=0}=\frac{ln(\frac{cos(x)}{cos(x)cos(h) - sin(x)sin(h)})}{h}
$$

Still the problem is same how to eliminate h

Comment: I think that somehow this standard limit is to be used but how ??

$$
lim_{x=0} \frac{ln(x+1)}{x} = 1
$$

Comment: Take Claude's advice to convert to a single log of a fraction, then use Vue's advice to use the trig identity for cos(x+h), then use the Taylor expansion of ln(1-y), and you will find that h cancels out in the first term.

Comment: following Claude's advice 
$$
lim_{h=0} \frac{-ln(\frac{cos(x+h)}{cos(x)})}{h}
$$

then using identity
$$
lim_{h=0} \frac{-ln(\frac{cos(x)cos(h) - sin(x)sin(h)}{cos(x)})}{h}
$$

this converts that fraction into
$$
lim_{h=0} \frac{-ln(cos(h) - \frac{sin(x)sin(h)}{cos(x)})}{h}
$$

It is not $ln(1-y)$

Comment: Please add a backslash when typing $\lim$, $\ln$, and trigonometric functions.  For example, `\lim` ($\lim$) instead of `lim` ($lim$).

Comment: I will remember that in future

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\ln\sec(x) = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{\ln(\sec(x+h)) -\ln(\sec(x))}{h}
$$

Using $\ln(A) - \ln(B) = \ln(\frac{A}{B})$

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\ln\sec(x) = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{\ln(\frac{\sec(x+h)}{\sec(x)})}{h}
$$

coverting $\sec(x)$ to $\cos(x)$ using $\cos(x) = \frac{1}{\sec(x)}$

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\ln\sec(x) = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{\ln(\frac{\cos(x)}{\cos(x+h)})}{h}
$$

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\ln\sec(x) = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{\ln(1+\frac{\cos(x)}{\cos(x+h)}-1)}{h}
$$

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\ln\sec(x) = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{\ln(1+\frac{\cos(x) - \cos(x+h)}{\cos(x+h)})}{h}
$$

multiplying and dividing by $\frac{\cos(x)-\cos(x+h)}{\cos(x+h)}$

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\ln\sec(x) = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{\ln(1+\frac{\cos(x) - \cos(x+h)}{\cos(x+h)})}{h}\frac{\frac{\cos(x)-\cos(x+h)}{\cos(x+h)}}{\frac{\cos(x)-\cos(x+h)}{\cos(x+h)}}
$$

repositioning

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\ln\sec(x) = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{\ln(1+\frac{\cos(x) - \cos(x+h)}{\cos(x+h)})}{\frac{\cos(x)-\cos(x+h)}{\cos(x+h)}}\frac{\frac{\cos(x)-\cos(x+h)}{\cos(x+h)}}{h}
$$

seperating limit

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\ln\sec(x) = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{\ln(1+\frac{\cos(x) - \cos(x+h)}{\cos(x+h)})}{\frac{\cos(x)-\cos(x+h)}{\cos(x+h)}}\lim_{h\to0} \frac{\frac{\cos(x)-\cos(x+h)}{\cos(x+h)}}{h}
$$

As $h$ approaches 0 so does $\frac{\cos(x)-\cos(x+h)}{\cos(x+h)}$ as the numerator beging to approach $0$. ($\cos(x) - \cos(x)$)

let us assume $t = \frac{\cos(x)-\cos(x+h)}{\cos(x+h)}$ and hence t approaches $0$ when $h$ approaches $0$

hence equation turns out to be

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\ln\sec(x) = \lim_{t\to0} \frac{\ln(1+t)}{t} \lim_{h\to0} \frac{\frac{\cos(x)-\cos(x+h)}{\cos(x+h)}}{h}
$$

Using the standard limit $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{ln(x+1)}{x} = 1$

Therefore

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\ln\sec(x) = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{\frac{\cos(x)-\cos(x+h)}{\cos(x+h)}}{h}
$$

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\ln\sec(x) = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{\cos(x)-\cos(x+h)}{h\cos(x+h)}
$$

Applying $\cos(A) - \cos(B) = -2\sin(\frac{A+B}{2})\sin(\frac{A-B}{2})$

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\ln\sec(x) = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{-2\sin(\frac{2x+h}{2})\sin(\frac{-h}{2})}{h\cos(x+h)}
$$

Bringing the $-2$ down

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\ln\sec(x) = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{\sin(\frac{2x+h}{2})\sin(\frac{-h}{2})}{\frac{-h}{2}\cos(x+h)}
$$

rearranging

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\ln\sec(x) = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{\sin(\frac{2x+h}{2})}{\cos(x+h)} \lim_{h\to0} \frac{\sin(\frac{-h}{2})}{\frac{-h}{2}}
$$

Using standard limit $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{sin(x)}{x} = 1$

Therefore

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\ln\sec(x) = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{\sin(\frac{2x+h}{2})}{\cos(x+h)}
$$

Putting $h = 0$

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\ln\sec(x) = \frac{\sin(\frac{2x}{2})}{\cos(x)}
$$

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\ln\sec(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}
$$

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\ln\sec(x) = \tan(x)
$$

Comment: There is also a possibility of using `chain rule` in terms of the first principles, look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/757989/proving-the-chain-rule-by-first-principles).

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx} {\ln(\sec x)}=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{-ln(\frac{\cos(x)\cos(h) - \sin(x)\sin(h)}{\cos(x)})}{h}$

$\displaystyle= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{-\ln{(\cos h-\tan x \sin h)}}{h}$

$\displaystyle=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{-\ln[({1- \tan x \tanh)(\cos h)}]}{h}$

$\displaystyle=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{-\ln({1- \tan x \tanh)}-\ln{\cos h}}{h}$

$\displaystyle=\lim_{h \to 0} -\frac{\ln({1- \tan x \tanh)}}{h}-\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\ln{\cos h}}{h}$

$\displaystyle=\lim_{h \to 0} {\frac{\ln({1+(-\tan x \tan h))}}{-\tan x \tan h}}{\frac{\tan x \tan h}{h}}-\lim_{h \to 0} {\frac1{\cos h}}{(-\sin h)}$
(Using L'hopital Rule, since ${\ln{\cos h}}\to 0, {h}\to 0$)

$\displaystyle=\lim_{\tan x \tan h \to 0} {\frac{\ln({1+(-\tan x \tan h))}}{-\tan x \tan h}} \lim_{h \to 0} {\frac{\tan x \tan h}{h}}+\lim_{h \to 0} {\tan h} \; (\because h \to 0 \implies \tan h \to 0 \implies \tan x \tan h \to 0)$

$\displaystyle=1. \tan x \lim_{h\to 0}  \frac{\tan h}{h} +0 \;(\because \lim_{y\to 0} {\ln{(1+y)} \over y}=1)$

$\displaystyle= \tan x \lim_{h\to 0} \sec^2{h}=\tan x . 1$ (Using L'hopital Rule, since ${\tan h}\to 0, {h}\to 0$)

$=\tan x$

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is in the spirit of the question, but we can also try proving the chain rule in the special case $(\ln \circ \sec)'(a)=\ln'(\sec a) \cdot \sec'(a)$. Note that
$$
\lim_{x \to a}\frac{\ln(\sec x)-\ln(\sec a)}{x-a}=\lim_{x \to a}\frac{\ln(\sec x)-\ln(\sec a)}{\sec x-\sec a} \cdot \lim_{x \to a}\frac{\sec x-\sec a}{x-a} \label{*}\tag{*} \, .
$$
For the first limit on the RHS of $\eqref{*}$, we can make the substitution $u=\sec x$. As $x\to a$, $u\to\sec a$, and so
$$
\lim_{u \to \sec a}\frac{\ln(u)-\ln(\sec a)}{u-\sec a}=\ln'(\sec a)=\frac{1}{\sec a}
$$
Since the second limit on the RHS is $\sec'(a)=\sec(a)\tan(a)$, we get that
$$
(\ln \circ \sec)'(a)=\tan(a) \, .
$$